# Ignore full lines with sed

Tags: sed, tcsh

I've searched high and low across the internet, but I can't seem to find an answer that satisfies this question - I need to use `sed` to display all lines in a file, excluding a group of them.

I'm not trying to remove them, nor rewrite them to be comments, but to simply not display them, and that's the issue I've had with searching online. No matter how I word it, I get results related to doing performing said actions.

I've tried the negation symbol within `sed -n '35,45'p /dir/file`, but I've not gotten any positive results. What am I forgetting?

Comment: Could you clarify on what you mean by: "excluding a group of them"? What are you considering as a "full" line?

Comment: The -n 'p' combo is not negation. `sed -n '35,45p' file` actually excludes everything but the range 35-45.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us a specific example and the output you would like to see form it.

Comment: @Dani_l I wasn't meaning to say that the combo was the negation, I meant it to mean that I would add a negation. However, I didn't fully understand exactly what sed was actually doing, or that it was, essentially, an output editor. I'd thought the `d` command would modify the file itself, not he output. The answer given below details what I've misunderstood about sed

Comment: @ElixirofLove What I meant was that I'd be excluding a range of lines (in this case, lines 35-45 would not be displayed). Regarding the full line, rather than removing lines that match a specific character, I'd remove every line in the range

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To display all lines *except* lines 35 to 45, use the `delete` command:

```
sed '35,45d' /dir/file
```

This does not alter the original file.  It just excludes the line range from the output.

#### Example

Consider this test file:

```
$ cat file
1
2
3
4
5
```

We can exclude lines 2 to 4 with:

```
$ sed '2,4d' file
1
5
```

Comment: What I hadn't understood prior was that the original file was not being altered. I had been processing in my head that using the `d` command would delete the range from the file entirely

Comment: @BradB By definition `d` sed-command does deletes, but while the `sed` command doesn't have the `-i` option, it won't alter the file. From  `man sed --i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]    edit files in place (makes backup if extension supplied)`